# Make deletes intermediate files, even though I use .SECONDARY or .PRECIOUS

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

At the end of my build, make deletes a file:

```
Removing intermediate files...
rm some/dir/myfile.inc
```

I want to keep it to make later builds faster, but I have not been able to. Either one of these two lines should force make to keep all intermediate files, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638275/undo-intermediate-files-deletion-how-to), but they have no effect:

```
.SECONDARY:
.PRECIOUS:
```

If I spell out the exact file path it does keep the file:

```
.SECONDARY: some/dir/myfile.inc
```

If but this does not work

```
.SECONDARY: %.inc
```

Is the `.SECONDARY` rules being ignored because of a later rule like this is more specific?

```
%foo.o %foo.h %foo.inc: some_other_file
    dosomething
```

Comment: What version of make are you using? I don't think `.SECONDARY` takes patterns only explicit targets. `.PRECIOUS` takes patterns but I think they need to exactly match the pattern of a pattern rule.

Comment: GNU Make 3.81. The accepted answer to [Undo intermediate files deletion - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638275/undo-intermediate-files-deletion-how-to) implies that patterns should work.

Comment: Yes. Patterns do work for `.PRECIOUS` (which I said). You are trying them with `.SECONDARY` (which is different). But I think `.SECONDARY:` with no prerequisites should work for 3.81 (but wouldn't with 3.80 and earlier I believe). (And `.PRECIOUS:` with no prerequisites doesn't mean anything I don't think.)

Comment: I remember hitting a similar issue, updating make version helped that time. Too bad I can't remember make versions involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why .SECONDARY does not work with patterns (%) while .PRECIOUS does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090032/why-secondary-does-not-work-with-patterns-while-precious-does)