# Why does gnu make delete this file?

Tags: gnu-make

Consider this `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all

all: main.txt

main.txt: build/main.txt
    cp build/main.txt .

%/main.txt: %/data.txt
    cp $*/data.txt $*/main.txt

%/data.txt:
    touch $*/data.txt
```

After running `make`, `build/data.txt` is removed automatically. Why is this the case?

I tried adding `.PRECIOUS: build/%` to the file, but it it not help, the file was still removed. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo intermediate file deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638275/how-to-undo-intermediate-file-deletion)

Comment: @Joe As I have written, adding `.PRECIOUS build/%` does not work. It only works when explicitly naming the file. I want to preserve all files in the directory,

Comment: `.SECONDARY`, not `.PRECIOUS`, and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090032/why-secondary-does-not-work-with-patterns-while-precious-does for whether a pattern can be used there.

Comment: An even simpler solution is simply to list the intermediate file as a prerequisite of _some_ target.  It doesn't have to be a target you ever expect to run.  Even something like `keepme: build/data.txt` is sufficient to force the file to be non-intermediate.  Maybe it would be useful to you to create a rule that builds just the data and you create a rule like `data: build/data.txt`

Comment: I urge you to _NOT_ use `.PRECIOUS` for this.  Declaring the target precious has other, probably unpleasant side-effects.  For example, if your build is killed while the `build/data.txt` file is half-written then declaring it `.PRECIOUS` will prevent make from cleaning it up.  That means the next run of make will see that half-built file with a newer timestamp and decide it's up to date and not rebuild it, causing problems until you go in and delete it by hand.  `.PRECIOUS` has a specific use and should not be used only for its side effect of disable intermediacy.

Comment: If you want to force something to not be intermediate, the best way is to make it a prerequisite of some target as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)

> You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target .PRECIOUS to preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns match that file’s name.

the prerequisite for`.PRECIOUS` needs to be the (exact) target pattern of an existing implicit rule.

In your case this would be `%/data.txt` instead.

The documentation hints at this, but is not particularly clear about it.

As a side note: As far as I can tell `build/main.txt` is not automatically deleted since it is explicitly named as a prerequisite for the `main.txt` target and `build/data.txt` is automatically deleted since it is never explicitly named.